# How to change URL names in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

This is my first time round using Umbraco and I have created Document Types / Pages using the wrong naming format and now this has transpired into my page URL's, for instance `/about-page/`. How would I go about changing them to `/about` as I have searched the back-end admin panel and there dose't seem to be an option to change their `link to document` values.

Would anyone be able to provide a simple code based example using umbracoUrlAlias or umbracoUrlName how I could change this preferably in Razor.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Editing @run yards Solution by digbyswift help in comment

**Correct Solution:**

1. Create **Property** on in **Document Types** which applies to all pages you want to change the URL
2. Call the name anything you want e.g Page URL and Possibly give it a new tab.
3. Call the alias **umbracoUrlName**
4. Type as **text sting**
5. Should not be **Mandatory** (As when you start replacing `.Url` with `.umbracoUrlAlias` within the views it will need to be present)
6. Tab as **Generic**
7. Click **Save** on top right on the page

Added screenshot for starter kit on Umbraco v7.2.5
[image: Adding screenshot for starter kit on Umbraco v7.2.5]

Comment: I'm using Umbraco 7.4.3 and I can't see any tab called Generic properties. Is there any way to get this tab?

Comment: @cp100 It looks like before 7.4 this would add the property to the "Properties" tab (the one that has the "ID", "Created by", and "Last edited" properties among others.  Now you have to just add this property to a different tab. [See this Umbraco forum post](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/76098-how-to-add-properties-to-the-properties-tag).

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm very much misunderstanding your issue, you should just be able to change the name of your page and republish. This doesn't need an additional field, just change the value in the "Properties" tab and republish the page. This will automatically change the URL of the page.

Comment: you can also create a text field with alias `umbracoUrlName` if you need the part of the url to be something other than the 'urlified' node name. (also if you want to redirect traffic from the old url to the new one I recommend the urlTracker package http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker)

Comment: Of course, but sometimes the simplest approach is the best. You should add your comment as an answer though as the OP did ask for an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a property called `umbracoUrlName` using a `TextString` property editor. If this has a value then it will generate the URL fragment for the page using this value, rather than the page name. This changes the URL for the page, rather than creating an alias, like `umbracoUrlAlias`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- Create property on in Document Types which applies to all pages you want to change the URL
- Call the name anything you want e.g Page URL and Possibly give it a new tab.
- Call the alias **umbracoUrlAlias**
- Type as **text sting**
- Make it **required** (As when you start replacing `.Url` with `.umbracoUrlAlias` within the views it will need to be present)
- Go into all your pages and rename them using the property you just created
- Now with your code, say with the navigation where you have used `.Url` change it to `.umbracoUrlAlias` and the new URL's will be used.

Note if you don't use `.umbracoUrlAlias` the links will still be active i.e. they work but they won't be displayed in the address bar as `.Url` spits out the original ones associated with the page.

Comment: This is overkill when you can just change the name of your document and republish it. If you need to override the URL you need to use `umbracoUrlName` and it should _not_ be mandatory as this forces the user to essentially repeat the bad practice you have mistakenly started. Either way, if you need a separate page title, you should add a separate `pageTitle` field and use an event to pre-populate this on `Newing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply on URL names in web.config:

In  section find:

```
<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="false" />
```

this will set url names for new created items to name.aspx

If you set this to 'true' then new items will be named like /name/

Additionaly you might want to avoid of Handling some urls by Umbraco pipline, just use this setting - add URLs which must be bypassed:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd" />
```