# Change URL in Umbraco root node

Tags: umbraco

I am new to Umbraco. I am using Umbraco 7.4.3.I need to change URL(link to document) of root node (landing page). I searched on the internet and found solution for previous versions but no solution describes how I can change URL in 7.4.3 or for later versions.

Structure of my content tree:

- Home [want to Change URL here (link to document) ]

  - Blog

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033540/how-to-change-url-names-in-umbraco) describe the solution but it is for previous versions:
I tried creating new tab, but don't figure out where is **Type** in version 7.4.3?

Many thanks.

Comment: joy!!!! I can change URL of landing page.
Type is basically type of property editor (PE) and PE is textstring.But now the issue is .aspx is not appearing at the end of URL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the URL at the root node I used ***umbracoUrlName*** this property preserve .aspx at the end of URL,However,***umbracoUrlAlias*** doesn't.

Hope it is helpful for others.

Comment: The `umbracoUrlAlias` is used for changing the URL of the current page (rather than letting Umbraco handle URL creation in the normal way). This is great if you want to create unusual structures, but shouldn't be used to create some sort of redirect (as this is more like a bug than a feature).

Comment: What happens when you go to the route of the site? Does it redirect you to the blog or fail to render any page?

Comment: @harvey as I only wanted to change URL name so both URL work for me e.g.   website\Umbraco and website\Umbraco\myblog to serve the root node.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the user to your blog page from your homepage, you need to create a property with alias `umbracoRedirect` on your homepage. You can then use the `Content Picker` property type to pick a node you want to redirect the user to (in this case, the blog).

There's a really good video here which shows how it can be done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJOsdtq9FQo

Comment: I know redirect property, but I wanted to change URL. I edit my question. My apologies. Your answer is right if re-direct is require,however,I only wanted to change URL, therefore. I used `umbracoUrlName` property.